KB5044277 update failed with error 0x800F0922
I use win10 ltsc 2019 x64 as my OS, this month when I do Windows update, KB5044277 always fails with error 0x800F0922, I have met this error before , and doing a cleanup of DIR softwaredistributition will work, but this time I tried several times but still got this error, I have uploaded the error log here, I checked this log but found nothing useful for where the error located,I have searched this site with "0x800F0922", several reasons were pointed out, but I think the best way is to find specific error info from the log file
Update:
after a week from last update, I tried update again ,this time it shows success result(when update and reboot, it do not prompt for error and require reboot again),so problem disappeared by itself, but more strange is that the update history panel still show the update is error with the same error code. I checked winver and some updated files, I think the update is really ok now
So maybe for such cases, the only thing to do is just wait for while...
Update these info to just for someone who met the similar situation.

The log is from a week ago (13th). So what was the last update successfully installed? When was it installed? I suspect you have not had any update successfully installed for months. Typical with these sort of errors.

@Ramhound  I updated routinely(auto update is turned on), last big update(monthly update) for September was successful, some even before update met 0x800F0922 error occasionally, but after delete "softwaredistribution" directory, the problem was solved, but this time this can not solve the issue , the log file is edited by myself to only show this time's update info
